# Redirecting Users via their Country in PHP

Tags: php, web

I'm trying to redirect a user to an appropriate page with respect to their country in PHP. Eg. US - mysite.com, Australia - mysite.com.au. I already have the IP address via this function and want to use this site to get their country: `http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=`.

```
if (getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR)) { 
    $ip_address = getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR); 
    echo $ip_address;
} else { 
    $ip_address = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR);
    echo $ip_address;
}

ip_address_to_number($ip_address);
```

Comment: Instead of calling an API you might want to look into using [GeoIP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using [NetImpact's API](http://www.netimpact.com/), but can you tell us specifically what the problem is? All you did was tell us what you're trying to do but you never told us how your current code is malfunctioning.

NOTE: Netimpact has shut down. They have migrated users to [KickFire](https://kickfire.com/kf-api), which has a broader API offering: IP2GEO, IP2Company, Domain2IP.

However, if all you want to do is get the content of that URL it's really easy. Just put this in your PHP page:

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$url = 'http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=' . $ip;
$country = file_get_contents($url);
// Do something with the country, I am forwarding to a subdomain here but you can
// do whatever you like.
header('Location: http://' . $country. '.mysite.com');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've managed to get that working but it is giving the error: Cannot modify header information when redirecting a page:                  if ($Country == "US")
  {
   header('Location: http://mysite.com');
  }
  
  else if($Country == 'AU')
  {
   header('Location: http://mysite.com.au');
  }

Comment: You must have output before the header. If you don't feel like changing any of the existing code, just buffer the output. Put this at the top of your page before anything else: ob_start();